# prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x}$ doesn't exist

Tags: limits

how we can prove this $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x}$$ doesn't exist
in the 'precise' way.

it's not difficult to see that  $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ doesnn't exit so we can conclude the result. or by Taylor expansion but I am looking for a different method.

Comment: It suffices to show that, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there are $x_1,x_2 \in (0, \varepsilon)$  such that $f(x_1) > 1/2$ and $f(x_2) < -1/2$ (say).

Comment: In general, if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ does not exist and $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)$ exists and is nonzero, then $\lim_{x \to c} g(x)f(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\sin{x}\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$. I am assuming that by "precise" you mean a rigorous proof of your problem. To show $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ doesn't exist, it suffices to show that given two sequences $x_n,y_n$ approaching to zero, $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) \ne \lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n)$.  Consider sequences $x_n = 1/n\pi$ and $y_n = 1/(2n\pi+\pi/2)$, then $f(x_n) = 0 \to 0$ and $f(y_n) \to 1$.